# Subcategory inside category in the Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show subcategory inside the main category. My table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Eyx.png). but when i print_r($cat_id) it returns only the last id of the category. How can I fix this? Here is my controller:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_categories_for_courses();

            foreach($data['categories'] as $ct){

                        $cat_id = $ct['id'];        
                }



            $data['subcategories'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_subcategories_for_courses($cat_id);

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('courses/courses-grid-fullwidth', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

and here is my model:

```
public function get_all_categories_for_courses() {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => NULL));
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_all_subcategories_for_courses($cat_id) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $cat_id));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

and here is my view page:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 incat">

             <h4>
               <a href="#" class="catname"><i class="fa <?= $cat['icon']; ?>" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <?= $cat['name_rus']; ?></a>               
             </h4>

            <ul>
              <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcat): ?>
              <li><a href="#"><?= $subcat['name_rus']; ?></a></li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cause `$cat_id` inside loop is always replaced with next value, so it only store the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do this

```
<?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 incat">

             <h4>
               <a href="<?= site_url('/courses/category/'.$cat['category_slug']); ?>" class="catname"><i class="fa <?= $cat['icon']; ?>" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <?= $cat['name_rus']; ?></a>               
             </h4>

            <ul>
            <?php 
            $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('parent_id' => $cat['id']));
            ?>

              <?php foreach($query->result() as $subcat): ?>
              <li><a href="<?= site_url('/courses/category/'.$subcat->category_slug); ?>"><?= $subcat->name_rus; ?></a></li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: However it's generally best practise to put things like database queries into the controllers and models rather than into the views. Not only is it cleaner, but it's also better for caching.

Comment: @AndrewGould however I tried also, it did not work properly. How can we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As Ukasyah said in a comment on your question, you're overwriting the `$cat_id` value each time you loop through your categories.

What you will need to do is get an array populated with the IDs and use `$this->db->where_in()` to match an array rather than a single value.

Your controller will need to look more like this:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_categories_for_courses();

$cat_ids = [];
foreach($data['categories'] as $ct){

    $cat_ids[] = $ct['id'];
}

$data['subcategories'] = $this->courses_model->get_all_subcategories_for_courses($cat_ids);

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('courses/courses-grid-fullwidth', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

While you will need to change your model function to look like this:

```
function get_all_subcategories_for_courses($cat_ids) {
    $query = $this->db->where_in('parent_id', $cat_ids)->get('categories');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Best of luck.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/courses_model.php

Line Number: 34

Backtrace: